# Does Pyodbc treat SQLWarnings as errors?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am writting Python code to connect to a MS SQL Server using Pyodbc.

So far, things have been going smoothly and I managed to call several Stored Procedures on the database.

I have now, however run into troubles. The stored procedure I am calling is outputting sqlwarnings regarding null values

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation. (8153)
```

While this is something that could/should be treated in the SQL part I would like to simply ignore it for now on the Python level.

The code is called in a fairly standard way (I think), like so (not providing a minimal code for now)

```
conn = None
    try:
        #Connection is created in another class, but retrieved here. Works ok.
        conn = db_conn.connect_to_db()

        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute(str_sql)

        # This is a hack, but I think is unrelated to the issue
        # Sorry I haven't found a better way to make pyodbc wait for the SP to finish than this
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025109/having-trouble-calling-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-from-python-pyodbc

        while cur.nextset():
            time.sleep(1)

        cur.commit()
        cur.close()

        return True

    except db.Error as ex:
        log.error(str(ex.args[1]))
        raise ConnectionError(ex.args[1])
```

The problem is the ConnectionError is raised on the SQLWarning. Can pyodbc be configured to ignore this?

Related posts tells me to turn off the ANSI Warnings on the Stored procedure, but I think that is a work around.

Other posts has stuff about importing '''warnings''' and catchAll() warnings, but this is tried, but didn't work. I guess since pyodbc sees it as an error thus the warning part never reached Python.

Did I misunderstand something or is it not possible?

Python version 3.7
Pyodbc version 4.0.32
ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Called from macOS

Comment: I can't replicate your error. For example, in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKM0f.png) the SQL would generate the message `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.`, but I get no error in Python.

Comment: Ok I guess that just about answers my question. There must be an error in my code then

Comment: Does your code behave any differently if you `pip install pyodbc==4.0.30` ?

Comment: @GordThompson I just tested and the behavior is the same.

Comment: Okay, thanks for checking. My concern was that 4.0.31 might have broken something.

Comment: @GordThompson no problems. From what Larnu could test then I should revisit my own code yet again to triple check.

Comment: @Larnu Can confirm I can also run your example, so it is either due to my hack with the wait or the fact it is a stored procedure.

Comment: I did dump the above code into a Proc as well and tried and couldn't replicate @TueChristensen . I suspect there's something we're missing here. If you take the to make a [mre] that would be really helpful.

Comment: @Larnu I have resolved my issue, though I still think something is weird. In my own answer I have posted something that I thought would reproduce the behavior, but instead simply doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I did somewhat resolve my issue.

The stored procedure actually did produce an error in my call. I found this after testing the call directly on the database.

So to answer my own question *no pyodbc doesn't treat warnings as errors*.

I did however only see the sql warning in the errors (or at least as far as I could tell). The real error thrown by a `THROW 50001, ......` was no where to be seen in the `pyodbc.Error`.

I tried to make a minimal reproducible example, but failed to do so. The following code seems to ignore the throwing of the error. I assume I made some mistake and this kind of sql string cannot be used. The expected behavior would be to land in the ERROR part, but instead the correct values are returned in the fetchall.

```
import pyodbc  

def test_warnings_after_errors():

    # Connect to your own MS SQL database 

    conn = None

    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute('''
        SELECT C1,
        MAX(C2) as MaxC2
        FROM (VALUES(1,1),
        (1,2),
        (2,4),
        (1, NULL),
        (2,4)) as V(C1, C2)
        GROUP BY C1
        THROW 51000, 'Will we get this error back?', 1;
        '''
        )

        result = cur.fetchall()

        print(result)
    except pyodbc.Error as error:
        print(error.args[1])
    
    print("Executed sql")
```

If I remove the whole select part the error is thrown as expected. The code runs as written in Azure Data Studio against the server and in that case it will return the error (and warnings regarding null before that).

To actually remove my error I had to do a cleanup of data, but that was totally unrelated to the issues posted here.

In my case I can live with the "weird" sqlwarning in case of error thrown, but it still puzzles me.